# Error "target already exists" when executing `hadoop fs -get ...`

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

There is no -f option like in the -put -f command  to Overwrites the destination if it already exists.

`[vagrant@gateway0 FlaskApps]$ hadoop fs -get  /user/17705.csv /output/17705.csv`

`` get: `/home/vagrant/output_IndiceA/17705.csv': File exists ``

Comment: Which hadoop version? `-f` is available in 3.0 https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#get

Comment: thanks for your reply , my hadoop version is  Hadoop 2.7.1.2.4.3.0-227